# Is it legal to kill or trap a skunk in Oregon?

Tags: oregon, animals

Do you need a permit? I’ve exhausted my search and don’t have a good resource. Is something like this county-by-county?

Answer (score 2):

[Skunks are "unprotected mammals"](https://www.dfw.state.or.us/wildlife/license_permits_apps/docs/Study_Guide_training_manual.pdf) under Oregon law, meaning that there are no closed seasons or bag limits. However, you must otherwise comply with general hunting regulations and licensing laws.